# If $f$ is measurable then it is constant.

Tags: measure-theory, functional-equations

> Let $f:(0,\infty)\to \Bbb R$ be such that $2f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y) \forall x,y\in(0,\infty)$.
>   Prove that if $f$ is measurable then it is constant.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se].
Can you please [edit] your post and write your attempts at solving the problem?
If your question is clear and focused on your specific difficulty and you show your effort in solving the problem, it's more likely to get good and helping answers.
By the way, take the opportunity to take the [Tour], if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on 
[ask], on 
[formatting help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) 
and on writing down equations using 
[LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Comment: Just curious, where is this problem from, if anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f : (0,+\infty) \to \mathbb R$ satisfies
$$f(x) + f(y) = 2f(x+y)\tag{*}$$
for all $x,y > 0$.

We claim $f(2a) = f(a)$ for all positive $a$.  Indeed,
\begin{align}
f(a)+f(a) &= 2 f(a+a),\quad \text{by (*)}
\\
2f(a) &= 2 f(2a)
\\
f(a) &= f(2a).
\end{align}

Now we have
$$
f(x)+f(y) = 2f(x+y) = 2f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)
\\
\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2} =f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)
$$
It is a [result of Sierpinski](https://books.google.com/books?id=P30Y7daiGvQC&pg=PA12&hl=en#v=onepage&q&f=false) that any Lebesgue measurable midpoint convex function is convex.  Applying this to $f$ and $-f$ we conclude $f$ is affine on $(0,+\infty)$.  But $f(1) = f(2)$, so $f$ is constant.